# how I can enter my login in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

[image]

I try with :

```
WebDriverWait(browser.window_handles[-1], 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername"))).send_keys("xxxxx")
```

Message Error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'

```
browser.find_element_by_id("pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername").send_keys("xxxxxxx")
```

Message Error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it the solution
I change this :

```
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
```

by

```
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
WebDriverWait(browser.window_handles[-1], 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername"))).send_keys("xxxxx")
```

should be

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername"))).send_keys("xxxxx")
```

This error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

is cause `browser.find_element_by_id("pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername")` did not return any web element so, we have got `NoneType`.

Please put some delays or hardcoded sleep before interaction like `time.sleep(5)` to see if that helps.

Comment: its return me AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'

Comment: Well, we are not using `is_displayed` anywhere in this question, that must be cause of something else in your code. Please share the entire error stack trace.

Comment: (base) C:\Users\u117235\Desktop\SecureCRT\Script>C:/Users/u117235/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/u117235/Desktop/SecureCRT/Script/New_project/demontage.py
c:/Users/u117235/Desktop/SecureCRT/Script/New_project/demontage.py:18: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50387/devtools/browser/f0d4e4e8-074f-4f3d-86ba-9046ef942296
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "c:/Users/u117235/Desktop/SecureCRT/Script/New_project/demontage.py", line 64, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername"))).send_keys("xxxxx")
  File "C:\Users\u117235\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)

Comment: File "C:\Users\u117235\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 128, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
  File "C:\Users\u117235\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 148, in _element_if_visible
    return element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'

Comment: (base) C:\Users\u117235\Desktop\SecureCRT\Script>[23684:3028:1012/153101.551:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:31:01.551] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Un pÚriphÚrique attachÚ au systÞme ne fonctionne pas correctement. (0x1F)
[23684:3028:1012/153101.575:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:31:01.575] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1204 Getting Radio failed. Chrome will be unable to change the power state by itself.
[23684:3028:1012/153101.590:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:31:01.589]

Comment: [23684:3028:1012/153101.590:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:31:01.589] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1297 OnPoweredRadiosEnumerated(), Number of Powered Radios: 0

Comment: This is where we have the issue `demontage.py", line 64, in <module> WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername"))).send_keys("xxxxx")`

Comment: Is it possible to share Page url ?

Comment: Sorry i cant its restricted area from my job